# Meteor AngularJS Ionic IOS device blank page

Tags: ios, angularjs, meteor, ionic-framework

I am building a Meteor hybrid app that using AngularJS and ionic, so I decided to use driftyco:ionic, since meteoric:ionic doesn't support Angular.
Everything works fine on web browser, however, it is blank when it runs on ios devices or simulator with no warnings or errors showing. I get rid of driftyco:ionic, content is able to show on ios devices. Thus, I believe there is something I did wrong with driftyco:ionic, so I got a blank page.

My repo https://github.com/yumikohey/bringMe ?

I deployed to 52.89.149.88(most updated) and bring-me.meteor.com(older version)

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Create mobile-config.js and add App.accessRule('*');
Re-run meteor